# closed form for a series with binomials and primes

Tags: prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

does the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n \binom{x}{p^n}$ have a closed form ? ($p$ prime)

this is a special case of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n \left(\sum_{k=p^n}^{p^{n+1}-1}a_k\binom{x}{k}\right)$ with the $a_k$'s $p$-adic numbers : I would like to have a closed form for the second one ... so I tried the "simpler" first one...

I would appreciate any (even partial, negative) answer .. because if I understood right the hints in Knuth "Concrete Maths" these series do not fit the good shape for closed forms.

Comment: Not sure if this can be helpful but starting from $$p^n\binom x{p^n}=\frac1{(p^n-1)!}\sum_ks(p^n,k)x^k,$$ where $s(\_,\_)$ are the Stirling numbers of the first kind, the power series expansion in $x$ has $$\sum_n\frac{s(p^n,k)}{(p^n-1)!}$$ at $x^k$. Now I looked at the Wikipedia for Stirling numbers and it turns out there is an [explicit formula](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1585) for them by Jerome Malefant; it gives $$\frac1{(k-1)!}\sum_n\frac1{(p^n-1)!}\sum_{2k_2+3k_3+...=p^n-k}(-1)^{k_2+k_3+...}\frac{(p^n+k_2+k_3+...-1)!}{k_2!k_3!\cdots2!^{k_2}3!^{k_3}\cdots}$$ as the coefficient at $x^k$.

Comment: It seems quite likely that there is no closed form.